# Accessing variable in module / Module scope in Python

Tags: python, scope, global

I would like to use a variable that I define in my application inside of a module.

The folder structure:

> myapp.py
>
> modules/checkargs.py
>
> modules/**init**.py (an empty file)

Main app (myapp.py):

```
_PARAMETERS = {
    'stuff': 'here'
}

from modules.checkargs import checkargs

if __name__ == "__main__":
    checkargs(sys.argv[1:])
```

checkargs.py:

```
def checkargs(argv):

    global _PARAMETERS;

    #more Python insanity here
```

The error:

> NameError: global name '_PARAMETERS' is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you should avoid this style of programming. Modules shouldn't rely on global variables defined in other modules. A better solution would be to pass `_PARAMETERS` in to `checkargs`, or move `_PARAMETERS` to a file that can be shared by multiple modules.

#### Passing the data to checkargs

Generally speaking, relying on global variables is a bad idea. Perhaps the best solution is to pass `PARAMETERS` directly into your `checkargs` function.

```
# checkargs.py
def checkargs(argv, parameters):
    ...

# myapp.py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    checkargs(sys.argv[1:], _PARAMETERS)
```

#### Creating a shared data module

If you have data that you want to share between modules, you can place that data in a third module that every other module imports:

```
# modules/shared.py
PARAMETERS = {...}

# myapp.py
from modules.shared import PARAMETERS

# checkargs.py
from modules.shared import PARAMETERS
```

#### Other solutions

There are other solutions, though I think the above two solutions are best. For example, your main program can copy the parameters to the `checkargs` module like this:

```
# myapp.py
import checkargs
checkargs._PARAMETERS = _PARAMETERS
...
```

You could also have `checkargs` directly reference the value in your main module, but that requires a circular import. Circular imports should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Why would it be defined? It's from a different module. Inside checkargs.py, you'd need to do:

```
from myapp import _PARAMETERS
```

However:

1. You shouldn't name it with a `_` then, since that implies private/protected variables.
2. You should probably pass the dictionary from `myapp` into the `checkargs` functions instead of importing it there. If you don't, you're creating a circular import, which is logically terrible and doesn't actually work.

Comment: This gives you circular dependencies, which should be avoided - myapp depends on checkargs, and checkargs depends on myapp

Comment: Yes, I see that you address that issue. However, your first statement says "you _need_ to do". "Need" is a very strong word here. In fact, the OP absolutely does not _need_ to do that. They _can_ do it, but it's a bad idea.  Maybe that's splitting a fine hair, but it's human nature to see an expert say "you need to do X" and so you go off and do it.

Comment: I softened that statement a bit... :)